# How to update table using 2 joins?

Tags: mysql, join

I have an eshop db and I've duplicated some products in order to move them to a different category (`wholesale/retail`). I need to update the `category_id` for each product that has `'[CLONE]'` in it's name, to this is what I'm doing:

First, I check how many products need to be moved:

```
select p.product_id, pd.product, pc.category_id
from cscart_products p
join `cscart_product_descriptions` pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id
join `cscart_products_categories` pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pd.product like '%CLONE%'
and pc.category_id = '17'; -- 17 is the current category_id
```

16 rows fetched;

Then, I perform the update:

```
UPDATE cscart_products_categories pc
join `cscart_product_descriptions` pd on pc.product_id = pd.product_id
join `cscart_products` p on pc.product_id = p.product_id
SET pc.category_id = '30'  -- the category to be moved to
WHERE pc.category_id = '17'
AND pd.product like '%[CLONE]%';
```

9 rows affected;

As you can see, only 9 out of 16 are being updated, obviously something's wrong in my update statement but what?

Comment: I've updated the original post because I had mistakenly put the values in the UPDATE query in the wrong order.

Comment: These 7 unaffacted may already be of the value 30 and therefor not affected?

Answer (score 1):

Your first query finds 16 rows that have `category_id` = 17.

Your second query changes 9 rows that HAD `category_id 30 to now have`category_id 17.

So after the second query, re-running the first query should discover 16+9=25 records with `category_id 17.

If you want to discover how many results will be updated, you should run the first query with `category_id = 30:

```
select p.product_id, pd.product, pc.category_id
from cscart_products p
join `cscart_product_descriptions` pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id
join `cscart_products_categories` pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pd.product like '%CLONE%'
and pc.category_id = '30'; -- the one that will be changed
```

-- 9 rows found

```
UPDATE cscart_products_categories pc
join `cscart_product_descriptions` pd on pc.product_id = pd.product_id
join `cscart_products` p on pc.product_id = p.product_id
SET pc.category_id = '17'
WHERE pc.category_id = '30' -- the category to be moved to
AND pd.product like '%[CLONE]%';
```

-- 9 rows affected

Comment: My wrong, I posted the values in the wrong order. It should had read 17, 30 not 30, 17. Please check my original post again, the results are right, my example was wrong.